# Getting 403 Forbidden error in Azure Logic app while adding members in MS Teams

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps

I am using Azure Logic App to add members in Microsoft Teams. It is running properly, but sometimes I get 403 Forbidden error with error message as "You do not have permission to perform this operation" and this error is intermittent.

I have checked my connection with Teams and it is correct as my Azure Logic app is running properly but this 403 error is occurring intermittently and I am not able to figure out the root cause for the same.

Hence needed your help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to some test, we can't add **guest** users of AAD into teams.

Here if I add a guest user in AAD to teams, it will show 403 Forbidden error.

[image]

Comment: They are not guest users. They are the employee of the same company. I am testing Logic App via postman.

Comment: Issue has been resolved. There was some permission issue. So, our IT team has resolved the issue

Comment: @svw1105 Ok, great.